# FilterExpression works just with comparator '=' in DynamoDB Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make use of FilterExpression in my Query in DynamoDB. However, it is not accepting any comparison operator, but **equals**. My aim is to use **grater than**

This query bellow works just fine using '=' operator

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'OrderBook-dev',
    
    KeyConditionExpression: 'order_type = :value', 
    FilterExpression: "#v = :val", // Equals is working fine but fails with '>'
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#v': 'amount'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ':value': 'BUY',
      ':val': 5
    },
    ProjectionExpression: 'amount, price',
    ScanIndexForward: true
    
};
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

If I replace it to '>' I get this exception

> :"Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "&", near: "#name >""

[image]

I think I am addressing [AWS's recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) when using **Filter Expressions for Query**, so I am out of ideas. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: can you show the table scheme? It's strange if you can't query through that params with ">"

Comment: also the error message tell us something differs to your description. It tells a problem  with "&" char, are you sure you wrote the correct FilterExpression statement?